# Sequences in Oracle to Identity columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I need to 'migrate' a table in Oracle, this table has a primary key column with a sequence and a trigger to autoincrement this column mentioned, the process is detailed [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonumber-and-identity).

The question is, I want to migrate this table to SQL Server put I want to take advantage of the identity feature. How can I tweak the table in SQL Server? Taking in count the fact I need to migrate the data and I don't want problems with the autoincrement column; will I lost the previous id assignation in Oracle?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? If 2012 or above, you can use a sequence instead of an identity column

Comment: @BenThul SQL Server 2014; this derives to another question: which is better? sequences or identity columns?

Comment: Pros and cons. Sequences are a little easier to deal with from an administrative standpoint (no nonsense about identity_insert) and in the future you can change the sequence easier than you can an identity. Also, I've read that sequences are more performant than identity columns, though I've never been in a situation where identity value generation has been my bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

No, you create the table with an identity column, like

```
MyID int identity([your max ID],1)
```

then when you insert the oracle data, prior to the insert run this command

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MYTABLE  ON

/*insert your records*/

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MYTABLE  OFF
```